Why my discord modal when i click didn't close?
When i clicked the button modal discord always an error. I dont know why my discord modal error
I want when i click the submit button, discord modal closed, but here still open. and show error on discord modal.
My error code:
const user = interaction.user.id

            const modal = new ModalBuilder({
                customId: `createChar-${interaction.user.id}`,
                title: 'Create Character',
            });
        
            const CharacterName = new TextInputBuilder({
                customId: 'characterName',
                label: 'Input your (fisrtname_lastname)',
                style: TextInputStyle.Short,
            });
        
            const PasswordInput = new TextInputBuilder({
                customId: 'characterPassword',
                label: 'Input your Password', 
                style: TextInputStyle.Short,
            });
            
            const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(CharacterName);
            const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(PasswordInput);
        
            modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);
        
            await interaction.showModal(modal)
        
            const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId === `createChar-${interaction.user.id}`;
        
            interaction
                .awaitModalSubmit({ filter, time:10_000 })
                .then((modalInteraction) => {
                    const CharacterName = modalInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('characterName')
                    const PasswordInput = modalInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue('characterPassword')
        
                    const user = interaction.user
        
                    const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setColor(0x0099FF)
                        .setAuthor({ name: `Scotty Roleplay` })
                        .setDescription(`Halo ${CharacterName}!,\nYou has been successfuly register UCP on **Scotty Roleplay**, please use your UCP name to login into server and register.`)
                        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
                        .addFields(
                            { name: '**UCP Name:**', value: `**${CharacterName}**` },
                            { name: '**Pin:**', value: '```\n4141\n```' },
                        )
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter({ text: 'Scotty Roleplay', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });            
        
                    user.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] })
        
                    modalInteraction.channel.send(`Your character name: ${CharacterName}\nYour Password: ${PasswordInput}`)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
                });     

Picture:
my error code

Please edit your question and add a tag for the coding language(s). Also, please add the exact error as text into your question. Images are ok as supplemental info, but the error should be in the question itself, as text. It would also be helpful if you describe, in detail, the troubleshooting / debugging that you've done and what you found.

You have to defer or reply to the modalInteraction, in that way the modal won't give you an error!
Maybe do this:
modalInteraction.reply(`Your character name: ${CharacterName}\nYour Password: ${PasswordInput}`)

Instead of this:
modalInteraction.channel.send(`Your character name: ${CharacterName}\nYour Password: ${PasswordInput}`)

